# Socket в Android для всех Activity

Tags: android

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MyService extends Service {
Socket socket;
DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
     thread.start();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    try {
        dataOutputStream.writeChar('a');
        dataOutputStream.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    try {
        dataOutputStream.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            socket = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 56);
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
}
```

Пытаюсь написать сервис, который хранит один сокет для всех акивити но при вызове метода onstartcommand dataoutputstream = null. Что делать? Уже 3 день голову ломаю...

Comment: А что в логах по поводу `IOException` из треда?

Comment: Тред выполняется и даже дает коннект а вот дальше хз...

Comment: Может быть разница в том, что значение вы устанавливаете в одном потоке, а в onStartCommand попадаете из другого, который ничего не знает об этом?

Comment: А как сделать общий socket на все потоки или activity?

Comment: Тут проблема не в том, что другой поток чего-то там не знает. `onStartCommand` выполняется следом за `onCreate`, который в свою очередь просто запустил поток и на этом его дело кончилось. То есть когда вы уже пытаетесь писать в `dataOutputStream` сокет в потоке ещё не подключился. Вам нужно сделать очередь для работы с сокетом. Тем более что `onStartCommand` выполняется в главном потоке, в котором работать с сетью запрещено.

Comment: Спасибо, а как вообще контролировать такие вещи? В активити такие же проблемы, в java se нет таких проблем в принципе